# How to print on same line using two print statement in lua

Tags: lua

Example:

Input:

```
Print("hello")
Print("hi")
```

Output:

```
hello
hi
```

I want to output both "hello" and "hi" on the same line like `hellohi` without using concatenation.

Comment: `print( "hello","hi")`

Comment: `io.write("Hello"); io.write("\t"); io.write("Hi"); io.write("\n")`

Comment: Or/And: ```print(("\"%s\" \"%s\""):format("HELLO", "HI"):lower())```

Comment: ✅ You can patch a `luaB_print` c function and remove `lua_writeline` from the end. You'll need to recompile Lua though.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want using `io.write()`. This does not write a line break by default.

```lua
io.write("hello")
io.write("hi")
```

Output:

```
hellohi
```

To add line breaks simply add `\n` to your io.write e.g.

```lua
io.write("hello\nhi")
```

output:

```
hello
hi
```

Moreover, if you want to write a variable with a string:

```lua
Age = 18
print("Age: " .. Age)
```

where the `..` concatenates them together.